# How to change text color of QLabel using QAnimation?

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I have `QLabel` with some text set on it. I want to create animation which changes text color to red for 1 second and than changes it back to beginning value.

What I do in my code is:

```
QGraphicsColorizeEffect *effect = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect(myLabel);
myLabel -> setGraphicsEffect(effect);
QPropertyAnimation *declineAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(effect, "color");
declineAnimation->setDuration(1000);
declineAnimation->setStartValue(QColor(252, 40, 3));
declineAnimation->setEndValue(QColor(254,220,105));
declineAnimation->start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to you to change the color but what you are trying to do simply looks like reverting the animation after it completes.

```
QLabel* myLabel = new QLabel("Colorized text");
QGraphicsColorizeEffect* effect = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect(myLabel);
myLabel->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
QPropertyAnimation* declineAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(effect, "color");
declineAnimation->setDuration(1000);
declineAnimation->setStartValue(QColor(252, 40, 3));
declineAnimation->setEndValue(QColor(254, 220, 105));
declineAnimation->start(QAbstractAnimation::KeepWhenStopped);

QObject::connect(declineAnimation, &QAbstractAnimation::finished, declineAnimation, [declineAnimation]
    {
        if (declineAnimation->direction() == QAbstractAnimation::Forward)
            declineAnimation->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
        else
            declineAnimation->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
        declineAnimation->start(QAbstractAnimation::KeepWhenStopped);
    }
);
```

This creates an infinite loop of changing color, back and forth.
What you asked was only 1 occurrence. You can change the lambda in the connect to achieve that:

```
QObject::connect(declineAnimation, &QAbstractAnimation::finished, declineAnimation, [declineAnimation]
    {
        declineAnimation->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
        declineAnimation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection
);
```

Note: unlike the former case, the connection needs to be a queued connection here.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. However, transition between those colors is smooth. I wonder how can I make an animation which ,,jumps" between colors?

Comment: If by "jump", you mean switch from `QColor(252, 40, 3)` to `QColor(254,220,105)` skipping all the colors in between, then use a `QTimer`. You do not even need a `QGraphicsColorizeEffect` if you do that, just change the label stylesheet upon receiving the `QTimer::finished()` signal.